# In building the largest co-prime numbers and dividing them into each other would the product converge or diverge?

Tags: prime-numbers, infinite-product

Utilizing all prime numbers and alternating which goes in the numerator and denominator to create the largest co-prime numbers on top and bottom, would the product converge or diverge?

$$3/2*7/5*13/11 ... = $$

Comment: All the factors here are greater than $1$. Are they upside down?

Comment: Do you know the theorem about $\prod(1+a_n)$ and $\sum a_n$? Do you know about $\sum(1/p)$?

Comment: @Gerry I doubt he even knows product notation. This might as well be Greek to him: $$\prod_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{p_{2i}}{p_{2i - 1}}$$

Comment: @Robert, OK, let me try this: Joe, do you know any theorems about convergence of infinite products?

Comment: I understand infinite sums pretty well and I would assume infinite products work in a similar fashion?

Comment: If you have to make that assumption, then the question about primes is not the place to start. Better to find a good introduction to infinite products, and learn the basic theorems. Then come back and ask your question, or, better, answer it yourself. Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you must include @Gerry in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product is $$\prod\left(1+{a_p\over p}\right)\tag1$$ where the product is taken as $p$ runs through the alternate primes $2,5,11,17,\dots$ and $a_p\ge1$ is the difference between $p$ and the next prime. The product converges if and only if $$\sum{a_p\over p}\tag2$$ converges. It's well-known that $\sum p^{-1}$ diverges when the sum is taken over all primes $p$, and the same methods suffice to prove the sum diverges when taken over just every alternate prime. Since $a_p\ge1$, it follows that the sum in (2) diverges, so the product in (1) diverges.